# Accessing AWS RDS From external server - Mediatemple: Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

So i have a website hosted on mediatemple using wordpress but i am refusing to move it over to AWS, my problem is, i also have an iOS app which is using an Elastic bean stalk, RDS, S3 and EC2 instance to save and store data.
What i'm trying to do is access the RDS externally from my wordpress site to display data like images and so forth. i'm pretty new to AWS and i wasn't too sure if there is specific steps i'd need to take or if this is even possible, but some help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code to access the mySQL RDS:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host","username","password");

mysqli_select_db($link, "databsename");

function query() {
global $link;
$debug = false;


$args = func_get_args();
$sql = array_shift($args);


for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
    $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
    $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
}


$sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

if ($debug) print $sql;


$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

    $rows = array();

    if ($result!==true)
    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($rows,$d);
    }

    //return json
    return array('result'=>$rows);

} else {

    //error
    return array('error'=>'Database error');
} } ?>
```

Comment: You can access rds from anywhere, check your RDS firewall(Security group) inbound connection.

Comment: I'm not sure as to what i should be setting? am i supposed to allow IP Access for 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: Yes you can but your wordpress site ip will be enough

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Where would i find my site IP Address?